# How to bubble up an exception

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

in my MVC application I have a simple scenario: a controller that calls a business layer whose role is to just call an api. Code of the business service follows:

```
public class ApiCaller : IApiCaller
{
    public async Task<T> GetResponse<T>(Uri url)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            try
            {
                var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseBody);
            }
            catch
            {
                ..do something..
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For single responsibility concept I want the layer to just call the API and catch exceptions if something goes wrong. Since it's not its responsibility deciding what to return (in the controller above) in case an exception is thrown but only catching it, I want to bubble the exception up to the controller. Eventually the controller by seeing that the returned result gave an exception will return something, or if the service wasn't found will return a 404 or so on.. but it will be its responsibility deciding what to return, not the business service's. So my question is: what's the best practice to bubble up an exception of this case? Thanks!

Comment: If you don't need to do anything with the exception, then just ignoring it will cause it to "bubble up" through the call stack, until something catches it (which is where you would return `404`). 

If you **do** need to do something in the event of an exception (resource cleanup, server side logging, etc.) but you still want to have it bubble up, then you can still have your `catch` blocks - just end each one with `throw` so the exception still bubbles up to the next caller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the simplest cases, you can just let the exception bubble directly and catch it in the controller. If you want to get more complex, you can have the business layer catch expected exceptions and then throw its own expected exception type. The controller (or exception handling filter) then catches those business exceptions and translates them to an HTTP response code.